# Dynamic VLOOKUP + COLUMN + IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I need to keep updated a `COLUMN` number into `VLOOKUP` formula with `IMPORTRANGE`.

```
=vlookup(B5;IMPORTRANGE(url;"RIASSUNTIVO!B:CC");
     column(IMPORTRANGE(url;"RIASSUNTIVO!C1:C10"));FALSE)
```

The `COLUMN` formula gave me an error "The argument must be a range".

I really don't know how do that.

Comment: I think you should use the function COLUMNS, not COLUMN.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you can't include most of the other functions as arguments of COLUMN. Actually I'm not sure if there are any that could be used.

It looks like you expect the argument of COLUMN to be C1:C10 of any of several spreadsheets, so it always will return 3. Considering this, replace the COLUMN's arguments by 3:

```
=vlookup(B5;IMPORTRANGE(URL;"RIASSUNTIVO!B:CC");3;FALSE)
```